# D3.js prepend (similar to jQuery prepend)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, prepend

I like the usage of append in D3, and I'm looking for prepend.

Does this exist in D3?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can use

```
selection.insert(newElement[, anotherExistingElement])
```

For example:

```
selection.insert("div",":first-child")
```

The above code will insert a `div` before the first child of selected element. Check [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_insert) to learn more.

Another possible way of inserting elements before any node (including plain texts):

```js
var parentEl = d3.select("div").node();
parentEl.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), parentEl.childNodes[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  This is a plain text
  <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not, however insert before any plain text in the node/

Comment: The documentation moved here: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_insert

Comment: @AdamTolley any suggestion for how to insert before plan text?

Comment: @ben I have added a possible solution in the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 22):

**Selection.lower()**

`selection.lower()` will place an element as the first child of its parent.

Together with d3's [append](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append), `selection.append().lower()` can replicate jQuery's [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Since D3 v4+, D3 has both `selection.raise()` and `selection.lower()` methods. These are used most frequently to move elements in an SVG so that certain elements appear overtop of others, where ordering of SVG elements in the DOM determines draw order. But, they can be used for any element in the DOM.

Here's a quick demonstration using divs and paragraphs:

```js
var div = d3.select("div");

div
  .append("p")
  .text("Inserted")
  .lower();

console.log(div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
Text
<p> Child Paragraph </p>
</div>
```

The snippet takes a div with the following contents:

```
Text
<p> Child Paragraph </p>
```

And uses d3 to append a new paragraph and then lower it so that the structure is as follows:

```
<p>Inserted</p>
Text
<p> Child Paragraph </p>
```

And for comparison with with jQuery's prepend:

```js
var div = $("div");

div
  .prepend("<p>Inserted</p>");

console.log(div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
Text
<p> Child Paragraph </p>
</div>
```

**More Info**

The selection.lower() is implemented as such (see [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_lower) for more info):

```
selection.each(function() {
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this.parentNode.firstChild);
});
```